# JMeter: json request gets forbitten

Tags: json, authentication, jmeter

Im new at jmeter and java programming.

My problem is that if i put the login session into a "run only once controller" , the json request wont work(403,forbitten).

If i let the jmeter run the log in session every time with the json request, it has no problem, running smoothly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Not working:  http://s21.postimg.org/q6qafrr9j/not_works.png
Working : http://s21.postimg.org/4j1c5bqvb/works.png

Answer (score 0):

I would check the "clear cookies each iteration" flag in the HTTP cookie manager.
If it is set, the session information gets cleared on each iteration.